# numpy exp overflow with negative input in numpy where

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which is exactly the one linked below (long file on pastebin):

[Z.txt](https://pastebin.com/PcMqh0dV)

Here is what happens:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.loadtxt("Z.txt")

print (Z.dtype)
```

Output:

```
float64
```

Then, the (not that) funny part:

```
A = np.where(Z>=0, Z, 1*(np.exp(Z)-1) )
```

Output:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

There should not be any overflow since only negative values should be passed in `np.exp`.

What I tried is basically to rewrite hundreds lines of code cause I don't get it. Obviously that was useless.

The minimal value in this array is `-1226.4000021278084` and max is `1493.6944653206767`.

So I don't understand what's happening.

I'd just like to get rid of this overflow problem which is just not supposed to happen. I have no idea how.

Comment: You are getting a **warning**, this is because e^1493 will explode. The biggest value you can use inside exp for a 64 bit float is ```np.log(np.finfo(np.float32).max)``` which is equal to ```~709```.

Comment: The ```np.where``` is not  lazy evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.exp(1493)` is `e^1493`, right? We can rebase that to be equal to `10^648`.

When we ask numpy what the maximum value of a float64 is, it's `2e308`, which is wildly less than `1e648`.

```
>>> np.finfo(float)
finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

The where clause doesn't evaluate till after you calculate the `np.exp(Z) - 1` array.

You could fix this with `np.exp(Z, where=Z<0) - 1`.

In response to your comment:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Z = np.array([[1e11,-1e11]])
>>> np.where(Z>=0, Z, 1*(np.exp(Z)-1) )
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
array([[ 1.e+11, -1.e+00]])
>>>
```

Clearly it does raise the same warning.

Comment: @Synthase Your second example raises the same warning for the same reason. The warning just gets eaten.

Comment: my apologies, it indeed raises the same warning.  However using your fix I now get the "FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in exp" error. Which I think I can fix by myself. So I think we're good.

Comment: You get that error because your negative values are wildly underflowing the `1e-15` resolution of a float. You could consider adding another where clause to protect against anything less then the ~-35 that will underflow.

Comment: Yes I will, thank you much. I just need the curvy shape of the ELU so below a few unit I'll set to 0.